# Shader Reflection With DirectX11

Tags: directx-11

I'm a new learner of `DirectX11`, and recent I decide to use `VS2015` to run code.

I try to not use `EffectFrameWork11`, but there's a very unpleasure experience while use it.

I try to change the values in constant buffer, without `EffectFramWork`, I have to use Map Function,pseudo code just like:

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mapResource;
ConstBuffer* constStruct = nullptr;
auto result = m_d3dContext->Map(m_constantBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD,
    0, &mapResource);
if (FAILED(result))
{
    d3dHelper::ShowResultMessage(result);
    return;
}

constStruct = (ConstBuffer*)mapResource.pData;
constStruct->word = world;
constStruct->view = view;
constStruct->proj = proj;
m_d3dContext->Unmap(m_constantBuffer, 0);

m_d3dContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &m_constantBuffer);
m_d3dContext->DrawIndexed(indexCount, indexOffset, vertexOffset);
```

OK,it work well, but as you can see,I have to write two same struct in C++ code and HLSL code:

c++ code like this:

```
struct ConstBuffer
{
    XMMATRIX word;
    XMMATRIX proj;
    XMMATRIX view;
};
```

HLSL code like this:

```
cbuffer cbPerObject : register(b0)
{
    matrix worldMatrix;
    matrix projMatrix;
    matrix viewMatrix;
}
```

So,is there any convenient way to update member with Constant Buffer?

Comment: You should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK)

Comment: thanks friend,I have look it.But it just use the same way.So if there is another way?

Comment: why not use `EffectFrameWork11`? I think it's convenient to update data to use `EffectFrameWork11` than using dx11 directly. And DXTK is also good.

Comment: well, it's just because I'm new learner, I want to know if there's new way.
And I scanned briefly in DirectXTK, it also use Map Function.

Comment: IMHO it is good to NOT use EffectFramework11 OR DirectXTK and similar libs. They are big and cumbersome, and also especially the fx framework is based on a tech which was already killed by microsoft. It gives you also more raw power over your app if you do it by hand...the only thing convenient was that you could set passes and textures conveniently from the shader, but eventually I think you will write something that is much better than fx framework ever was

Answer (score 0):

No you most probably can't, and also, you need to write Map/Unmap code anyways. But, there is a bit of a light, you can get the byte position of the variable from shader reflection, but I think it does not help you much otherwise. In my framework I just have the struct filled out then I have a call which basically looks like this

```
gpu->CommitGPUResource<LetsSayAPointLight>(pointLightStruct);
```

and it basically does that what you wrote above, so don't worry about it, it is not ugly, it is a way how to deal with it.